# swapping values of database table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table that contain a list of properties that will be visible to user. but I inserted data in wrong format,I want to swap values of `[ActionName]` with `[ControllerName]` name without creating a temporary table.

```
 SELECT [MenuID]
          ,[MenuName]
          ,[MenuMasterID]
          ,[ActionName]
          ,[ControllerName]
          ,[ImageClassName]
          ,[MainOrderID]
          ,[SubOrderID]
      FROM [DEV_CMS_Medical].[dbo].[SEC_Menus]
```

Comment: Give a dummy name `[ActionName]` as `ControllerName` in your query

Comment: i want to update database values by swapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use assigment/aliasing if you want to swap only when querying

```
 SELECT 
       t.[MenuID]
      ,t.[MenuName]
      ,t.[MenuMasterID]
      ,[ActionName] = t.[ControllerName]
      ,[ControllerName] = t.[ActionName]
      ,t.[ImageClassName]
      ,t.[MainOrderID]
      ,t.[SubOrderID]
  FROM [DEV_CMS_Medical].[dbo].[SEC_Menus] t;
```

Use Update when you want swap underlying data:

```
UPDATE [DEV_CMS_Medical].[dbo].[SEC_Menus] 
SET [ActionName]      = [ControllerName]
    ,[ControllerName] = [ActionName];
```

Comment: @MuhammadNasir Be more specific when you formulate question.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE [DEV_CMS_Medical].[dbo].[SEC_Menus]
SET ActionNamec = ControllerName, 
    ControllerName = ActionName
```

Or IF you want show the data with out any manipulation just  use the alias name for required columns

Answer (score 1):

```
update dbo.SEC_Menus 
    set ActionName = ControllerName,
        ControllerName = ActionName
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to rename the column names like this:

```
sp_RENAME 'TableName.[OldColumnName]' , '[NewColumnName]', 'COLUMN'
```

For this you need to first set the OldColumnName to some dummy name. Something like this:

```
sp_RENAME '[SEC_Menus].[ActionName]' , '[ControllerNameDummy]', 'COLUMN'
```

Comment: You need intermediate step with dummy name. So 3 rename will be needed. Good that this touch only metadata.